# Create a list which has only one time each element from two other lists in Python

Tags: python, list, function, unique, element

I'm new in Python and I have to solve a quiz. Given two lists of fruits I have to input the missing code in order to return a new list with unique elements from the 2 lists. 
So the unique_fruits must have

["apples", "bananas", "pineapples", "cherries", "strawberries", "oranges", "grapes", "watermelon"]

I do not have to care about the order of the list.

So the given problem is the following

```
def unique_fruits(fruits1, fruits2):
   #write your code here

fruits1 = ["apples", "bananas", "pineapples", "pineapples", "cherries", "strawberries"]
fruits2 = ["oranges", "pineapples", "grapes", "oranges", "cherries", "bananas", "watermelon"]


print(unique_fruits)
```

My try is the following

```
    def unique_fruits(fruits1, fruits2):
       unique_fruits = list(set(fruits1 + fruits2))

    fruits1 = ["apples", "bananas", "pineapples", "pineapples", "cherries", "strawberries"]
    fruits2 = ["oranges", "pineapples", "grapes", "oranges", "cherries", "bananas", "watermelon"]

    print(unique_fruits)
```

But getting error "function unique_fruits at 0x7fd3067ffe18"

I have to write the missing code only were the # is.

The only way to get the result is when I have the following code

```
def unique_fruits(fruits1, fruits2):
   unique_fruits = list(set(fruits1 + fruits2))

fruits1 = ["apples", "bananas", "pineapples", "pineapples", "cherries", "strawberries"]
fruits2 = ["oranges", "pineapples", "grapes", "oranges", "cherries", "bananas", "watermelon"]
unique_fruits = set(listfruits1 + fruits2))
print(unique_fruits)
```

But as already mention have to complete my code where # is

What am I missing?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Don't name a variable `unique_fruits` inside a function named `unique_fruits`, ideally you would avoid this as you can get all kinds of name collisions. Name the variable in the function something else

Comment: Are you sure you're not missing something in the question? It's very odd that you're not calling the function they've asked you to make.

Comment: You have to call the function: `print(unique_fruits())`, and the function has to `return` something, which it currently doesn't.

Comment: Just to make it more clear the issue is closed, if you have the answer you're looking for, please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code. First of all, `function unique_fruits at 0x7fd3067ffe18` isn't an error, it's printing the location in memory of the function because you didn't include () after the function name, or any parameters for the function. Second, instead of defining a variable called unique fruits, you should be returning the value instead. The following works for me, let me know if you have any more questions:

```
def unique_fruits(fruits1, fruits2):
    return list(set(fruits1 + fruits2))

fruits1 = ["apples", "bananas", "pineapples", "pineapples", "cherries", "strawberries"]
fruits2 = ["oranges", "pineapples", "grapes", "oranges", "cherries", "bananas", "watermelon"]


print(unique_fruits(fruits1, fruits2))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply 3ddavies. Hard to study during holiday season...